# Align items vertically in a div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with an anchor inside and I want this anchor to take the whole width of the div however, I would like to have the text of the anchor to be centered within the div, it's not working for me. I have tried this code:

```css
  .actions {
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
  }
  .action {
    background: #ef5b2b;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    margin: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px; 
    position: relative;
  }

  .action a {
      display: inline-block;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <div class="action-left action">
    <a href="#" style="color: white">Hello 1</a>
  </div>

  <div class="action-right action">
    <a href="#" style="color: white">Hello 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why is this closed? Other questions are talking about just text.. I want the anchor tag to take the whole space of the div at the same time..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

The `.actions` container needs to be `flex` so that the two `actions` containers will be evenly spaced, side by side.

Each `.action` container will hold the two anchor containers (which will be 100% height and width). Therefore, the `.action` containers only need to be width/height 100% themselves.

The `a` tags within the `action` containers need to be 100% height/width so that they fill the entire `.action` container. BUT, to center the text vertically and horizontally, you can use flex so that you can use `justify-content: center` and `align-items:center` - which makes the content within them centered both horizontally (justify-content) and vertically (align-items).

```css
.actions {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
  }
  .action {
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px; 
    margin: 5px;
    background: #ef5b2b;
  }
  
.action a{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <div class="action-left action">
    <a href="#" style="color: white">Hello 1</a>
  </div>

  <div class="action-right action">
    <a href="#" style="color: white">Hello 2</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @cssyphus, but the anchor isn't taking the whole width of the div, meaning that the whole area isn't clickable.

Comment: OIC, I didn't understand that. Hang on...

Comment: it's working now, you did update the anchor code?

Comment: Yes. *(BTW, If you click the `edited 27 secs ago` link (between the `share/edit/delete/flag` line and the `answered x mins ago` line, you can see the details of each edit - what changed each time.)*

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your help. I don't know why they downvoted the questions, this site discourages people from asking, run by psychos. Thanks a lot to you +1